# Is the revvideograbber in working order with LiveCode 6.0.1 on Windows7 and *?

Tags: livecode

I'm wanting to use revvideograbber with Livecode 6.0.l on windows 7 to capture a single frame image from a video preview from a webcam. Is this possible? In researching I've seen reports of it being broken on windows or that it doesn't work with QT in windows.

As a side question I've also read that it has a an undocumented directshow capability. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

The revVideoGrabber external isn't available for LiveCode 6.0 and later yet. What is directshow?

Comment: The current viersion is Livecode 6.0.1 and release notes say they added revVideoGrabber support.

Comment: Directshow was Microsofts replacement for VFW (circa 1997) Part of DirectX package.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and I could get it to work on Windows 7 (32bit) using the VFW option, QT would not work at all.

I looked at the current source files for revVideograbber on github and see there is a source file for directshow support.  Absolutely no find able documentation on it though so may not be useful until some syntax on how to use it is released.

Comment: If you copy the external from 5.5.4 to 6.0.1, you can indeed make it work, but it is unreliable. E.g. the video always shows up in the wrong window, sometimes even a palette (the message box).